# How an I access data in map to set properties?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Using react-three-fiber, i'm trying to set a location of a object dynamically via state. I'm having a issue where if i'm sending in a state it doesn't actually reflect the data. It's very odd. Wondering if anyone knows what's up or how to change. I imagine I have to use some kind of hook or something?

```
<Canvas linear flat frameloop="demand" orthographic camera={{ position: [0, 0, 50], zoom: 20, up: [0, 0, 1], far: 10000 }}>
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                {moduleData.floor1.pins.map(e=>
                    <Pin pinInfo={e}/>
                )}
                <Scene mapImage={riverwalkMap}/>
            </Suspense>
            <MapControls enableRotate={false}/>
        </Canvas>
```

and then the Pin function:

```
function Pin(pinInfo){
    const pinTexture = useLoader(TextureLoader, setPinColor(pinInfo.pin_color));
  console.log(pinInfo)
    return(
        <>
        <mesh position={[5,-8,0]}>
            <planeGeometry args={[5,5]}/>
            <meshBasicMaterial map={pinTexture} toneMapped={false} transparent={true}/>
        </mesh>
        </>
    )
}
```

the console log in there returns:

```
{
  "pinInfo": {
    "pin_color": "yellow",
    "pin_position": {
      "x_pos": 5,
      "y_pos": 10
    },
    "popup_color": "green",
    "popup_content": "<p>Test</p>",
    "popup_title": "Test"
  }
}
```

but if I try to access anything in there like:

```
pinInfo.pin_position.x_pos
```

I get undefined. Anyone got any ideas on how I can access that data every time the data changes in that map call?

Comment: How are your pins retrieved? If it's from an async call, your first render (before having your data from you api) will be made with no values

Comment: So the pins are retrieved from HubSpot's module data. Essentially their React Boilerplate brings data over from their API and puts it into "moduleData'. I dont think it's async, but I'll try coding in some kind of logic that atleast does something on a first render and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I feel dumb. The answer is I didn't destructure the prop, so all I had to do was use:

```
pinInfo.pinInfo.pin_position.x_pos
```

To get it to work :v